# Web service for authenticating customers security

Tags: web-services, authentication, asp.net-web-api

I'm working on creating a web service to expose customer authentication to external vendors.  In this case the vendor is a wifi-provider.

My question is if they (the vendor) is POSTing a login and password to a service over SSL, is it a good idea to authenticate the vendor (to access the API) first?  I can see both sides of the argument.

**EDIT**

The end user will be entering their credentials on the vendor's side (ie on the vendor's login page)

Comment: What's the alternative?  Not having authentication?

Answer (score 0):

Vendors should never see your users' credentials. Instead the login form that the user enters their credentials on should submit directly to your server. If the username and password is correct it should redirect back to the vendor's site with a ticket id. The vendor's server can then take that ticket and ask your service if it's a valid ticket and for any relevant user information.